# Redirect if URL match defined strings using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect a if URL match defined strings using .htaccess in a single line code

If URL is

- http://example.com/mobiles/xyz/
- http://example.com/computers/xyz/
- http://example.com/books/xyz/

Redirect URL

- http://example.com/comingsoon/

I tried this but i want to define string (e.g. books, mobiles, books) instead of (.*)

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/xyz/?$    upcoming/index.html    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if i've understand correctly the question, but this should do the trick:

```
 RewriteRule ^mobiles|books|computers/xyz/?$ upcoming/index.html [NC,L]
```

Tested on https://regex101.com/